# Can we get list of Search Engines installed in a browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, search-engine, navigator

Can we get the installed plugins in a browser using 'navigator'
Is there any similar way to get the list of installed Search Engines in a browser using JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

The definition of "a plugin" is reasonably well understood, as a component that provides additional functionality to the page via its actions. It is reasonable to expose availability of individual plugins to the user interface, to enable it to make informed decisions as to the types of content being displayed.

An "installed search engine" isn't well defined and differs across different browsers, and also makes no difference to the functionality of an individual page or site; it's a user option that you'd not expect a page to need to know about, in the same way as (for example) you can't get a list of the current printers.

You should be able to write a plugin that JavaScript would be able to use to access this information (which would probably require access to the registry keys for each installed browser), but that would rely upon the user installing it in the first place.

Comment: how **write a plugin** to `Access this information` ?